# What could be generating this SQL.LOG file?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, log

I am trying to find out what is generating a log file named C:\SQL.LOG. The file has grown to 4 gigabytes in size.  The contents of the file look like this:

```
fserver        398-408   ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       16 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       16 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [       8] "emp_temp"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (8)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (-7)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (1)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (0)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)

cfserver        398-408 ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       17 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       17 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [      12] "emp_seasonal"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (12)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (-7)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (1)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (0)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)

cfserver        398-408 ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       18 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       18 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [       9] "emp_notes"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (9)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (-10)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (1073741823)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (0)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)

cfserver        398-408 ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       19 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       19 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [      12] "emp_firstaid"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (12)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (-7)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (1)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (0)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)

cfserver        398-408 ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       20 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       20 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [      10] "emp_active"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (10)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (-7)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (1)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (0)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)

cfserver        398-408 ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       21 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       21 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [      12] "emp_birthday"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (12)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (-9)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (4)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (0)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)

cfserver        398-408 ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       22 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       22 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [      19] "emp_anniversary_old"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (19)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (-9)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (8)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (0)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)

cfserver        398-408 ENTER SQLDescribeCol 
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       23 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2

cfserver        398-408 EXIT  SQLDescribeCol  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
                        HSTMT               019BF798
                        UWORD                       23 
                        UCHAR *             0x0465F100 [      15] "emp_anniversary"
                        SWORD                      256 
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0FE (15)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F4 (11)
                        SQLULEN *           0x0465F0EC (23)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F8 (3)
                        SWORD *             0x0465F0F2 (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an ODBC log. See [KB274551 How To Generate an ODBC Trace with ODBC Data Source Administrator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/274551).

Long story short check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.ini\ODBC` and change the key `Trace` from 1 to 0.

Comment: This setting is also available under the ODBC administration control panel. This is available from Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Data Sources (ODBC). If you're on a 64-bit machine you may also need to check the "ODBC (32-bit)" control panel applet. I don't know for sure that both of those update the same registry entry, so it may be worth looking under both of those if you're on a 64-bit box.